# Splitting a text file with hangman drawings to a list

Tags: python

I need to split this text file which contains the different segments of a hangman to separate drawings and store it in a list which must be returned by the function and stored in a variable so that I can  use it in the main program when the user gets a word correct or incorrect, I tried `str.split` and others but nothing seems to work.

```
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
```

Comment: They're constant size, just slice the list in steps of eight.  Would probably easier to construct them directly in the program rather than trying to load it from a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way, in this specific case, is to observe that empty lines split the figures. So try `split('\n\n')`:

```py
with open('hangman.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

lst = text.split('\n\n')
print(lst[0])
print(lst[-1])

#   +---+
#   |   |
#       |
#       |
#       |
#       |
# =========
#   +---+
#   |   |
#   O   |
#  /|\  |
#  / \  |
#       |
# =========
```

This assumes that the input text file is well-behaving: the empty line should not contain whitespaces (other than `\n` of course) and there is no trailing empty lines. If not, I guess you can easily modify the text file.